# Request.QueryString doesn't get the input names from html form

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, request.querystring

I need to take the username, email and password a user enters in an html form (in index.aspx) and use it in an asp.net code in another page (register.aspx in a folder called 'u').

This is the form:

```
<form action="u/register.aspx" method="post" id="regForm">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Full Name (Optional)" maxlength="16" />
            <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username" maxlength="16" />
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="32" />
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" maxlength="16" />
            <input type="password" name="repwd" id="repwd" placeholder="Repeat Password" maxlength="16" />

            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="signup" />
</form>
```

But, when I'm using Request.QueryString["fname"] for example, it doesn't take 'fname' from the form, it just takes a null.

What can I do to solve this? Is there a different method I can use to achieve the wanted result?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `QueryString` gets information from the query string surprisingly enough.  You have posted your form, you need `request.Form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
`Request.QueryString` contains information related to data added after ? in the URL (ex. http://www.contoso.com?mydata=1&param2=yy).

You have to use `Request.Form` to access "POST" data.

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** Apparently, my teacher was using the 'get' method (I used 'post'), which is why he used Request.QueryString. It works wonderfully now.

Answer (score 1):

QueryString will only give the parameters on the query string of the url check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want all the parameters you will need to use the [Params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said `Request.QueryString` contains data after the ? in url.

You can use `Request.Form` or if you want the data as part of the url, you can change your form element method attribute to "get"